# how to get the saved words in android dictionary

Tags: android, dictionary

I'm developing an app that can add words to **UserDictionary** and query from it.
when running the app on tablet device it work fine.
but when running it on non tablet device
and save an auto corrected word to my word list and query for it, it didn't retrieve the words.

so what I should to do to query and select all saved auto corrected word.

```
// this to add word to dictionary
    Uri dic = UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI;
    UserDictionary.Words.addWord(this, "word", 100, UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE_TYPE_ALL);

// this to query 
         Uri dic = UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI;
         ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
         Cursor cursor = resolver.query(dic, null, null, null, null);
         while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words.WORD));
            int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words._ID));
            String app = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words.APP_ID));
            int frequency = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words.FREQUENCY));
            String locale = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(UserDictionary.Words.LOCALE));
            Log.i("", "word: "+word+"\nId: "+id+"\nAppID: "+app+"\nfrequency: "+frequency+"\nLocale: "+locale);
         }
```

Comment: what do you mean by `it didn't retrieve the words`? The log is empty? You should save it on a `List` for later use.

Comment: @Aprian   I know, but I mean that the auto corrected word that I saved it in android tab, it saved to UserDictionay but in other android device it didn't saved to UserDictionary, so I want to know how to get the saved word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a word, the [Javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/UserDictionary.Words.html) suggests using UserDicrionary.Words.addWord.

To use the spellcheker, above Android 4.0, there's a [framework](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/spell-checker-framework.html#SpellCheckClient), along with a few examples of its use. Hope these help.